# MacOS Dynamic Port Forwarding (ssh -D)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, libssh2

I want to do `ssh -ND 888 root@0.0.0.0` functionality in my **macos app** can someone please suggest any idea ?

I tried with **libSSH** but not helpful I want to do `SOCKS5 Proxy`

> Swift or Objective-C both okay, just want something working... Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `NSTask` ?

Comment: @koen Tried but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had resolved this with SwiftNioSSH

https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssh

Its really good repo from Apple, right now in early stage but have really good feature